# How do I make the reported font em height consistent across machines

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, gdi+, text-rendering

I am calculating font metrics in a rendering service using C# .Net 4.5 running on four computers, three running running Windows 8.1, one running Server 2008 R2, all are up to date with various updates.

In the service code I use the following to get some font metrics:

```
int emHeight = font.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(font.Style);
int lineSpacing = font.FontFamily.GetLineSpacing(font.Style);
```

I then use these values to calculate the height in pixels to render some text to a bitmap using GDI+ DrawString.

I'm setting the Graphics options as follows:

```
gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
gfx.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

However the metric values being reported are different, and two machines agree it's one value and the other two agree it's a different value.

On machine 1 and machine 2 the em height is reported as 1000, on machine 3 and the server (machine 4) it is reported as 2048.

The line height on machines 1 and 2 is reported as 1213, and on machines 3 and 4 it is reported as 2371.

The resulting heights are 51 and 48, which are just different enough to cause problems.

I've been looking into font metrics and it seems you can specify the font design units per em in the font and the values are traditionally 1000 on a mac and more recently 2048 on Windows, however all machines are using the same binary font file.

Is there a way to tell the font to use design units I specify in the code rather than an arbitrary value retrieved from the operating system, OR is there a way to make this value consistent across all 4 machines by changing a system value or registry entry?

I've checked the visual DPI display settings and they are the same across devices as are the clear type settings. I'm not sure where any other settings are that will help.

Edit -

It doesn't matter what the values are, just that they are being reported inconsistently across the machines.

I'm loading the fonts using the Font and FontFamily classes and I have installed the same font files on all of the machines.

The font the issue became apparent on was FranklinGothicNew, but it affects many fonts including Eurasia, Greyhound, and Lightfoot.

I wrote a quick checking program to run on each machine to highlight the differences.

```
       foreach (var f in fontList) {
            try {
                var font = new Font(f, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
                int emHeight = font.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(font.Style);

                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", f, emHeight); 
            }
            catch {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", f, "unknown");
            }
        }
```

Comment: that is not how the units work. They are *typically* 2048 for TrueType outlines (which are not OS dependent) and *typically* 1000 for CFF with Type2 outlines (which are also not OS dependent), but they're free values and designers can set whatever they need. If you use the same, identical, font, you should see the same, identical, values. Are you loading from font, or are you trusting the systems to just have the same font installed? (generally not a good idea if you need pixel precision).

Comment: I realise that they could be anything, this isn't a problem, it's that they're being reported inconsistently. I'm loading the font using the Font and FontFamily classes and I've intalled the same fonts using the same font files across all of the machines

Comment: Can you update your post to explain that, and mention which font it is, so people can reproduce and verify what you're seeing?

Comment: Post updated with a bit more info.